# How to load a DDS file with mipmaps

Tags: directx, loading, mipmaps, dds

I believe there's a `D3DX` function that can load a `DDS` file with mipmaps but `D3DX` is deprecated. Any function/library that can load it and that's not deprecated? I need it for `DirectX` if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) which has a lightweight DDS loader which can load mipmaps for you. You can integrate it very easily (just include some headers in your project and that's it) and call `CreateDDSTextureFromFile` function to load a texture from disk. There is an even more robust loader one which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: I've downloaded it but used only DDSTextureLoader files (header + cpp) as I don't want or need a whole additional project in my solution. These 2 files however are light-weight, easy to integrate in the project and do exactly what I want! Many thanks!

Comment: I have one problem with this library, though: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75577/problem-with-sdk-os-version I'm saying that in case somebody else gets it too.